# python sort list of json by value

Tags: python, json, lambda, sorting

I have a file consists of JSON, each a line, and want to sort the file by update_time reversed.

sample JSON file:

```
{ "page": { "url": "url1", "update_time": "1415387875"}, "other_key": {} }
{ "page": { "url": "url2", "update_time": "1415381963"}, "other_key": {} }
{ "page": { "url": "url3", "update_time": "1415384938"}, "other_key": {} }
```

want output:

```
{ "page": { "url": "url1", "update_time": "1415387875"}, "other_key": {} }
{ "page": { "url": "url3", "update_time": "1415384938"}, "other_key": {} }
{ "page": { "url": "url2", "update_time": "1415381963"}, "other_key": {} }
```

my code:

```
#!/bin/env python
#coding: utf8

import sys
import os
import json
import operator

#load json from file
lines = []
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line: break
    line = line.strip()
    json_obj = json.loads(line)
    lines.append(json_obj)

#sort json
lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda k: k['page']['update_time'], reverse=True)

#output result
for line in lines:
    print line
```

The code works fine with sample JSON file, but if a JSON has no 'update_time', it will raise KeyError exception. Are there non-exception ways to do this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Write a function that uses `try...except` to handle the `KeyError`, then use this as the `key` argument instead of your lambda.

```
def extract_time(json):
    try:
        # Also convert to int since update_time will be string.  When comparing
        # strings, "10" is smaller than "2".
        return int(json['page']['update_time'])
    except KeyError:
        return 0

# lines.sort() is more efficient than lines = lines.sorted()
lines.sort(key=extract_time, reverse=True)
```

Comment: This works but you should avoid using namespaces that are for built-in library.

Answer (score 34):

You can use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) with a default value:

```
lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda k: k['page'].get('update_time', 0), reverse=True)
```

Example:

```
>>> lines = [
...     {"page": {"url": "url1", "update_time": "1415387875"}, "other_key": {}},
...     {"page": {"url": "url2", "update_time": "1415381963"}, "other_key": {}},
...     {"page": {"url": "url3", "update_time": "1415384938"}, "other_key": {}},
...     {"page": {"url": "url4"}, "other_key": {}},
...     {"page": {"url": "url5"}, "other_key": {}}
... ]
>>> lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda k: k['page'].get('update_time', 0), reverse=True)
>>> for line in lines:
...     print line
... 
{'other_key': {}, 'page': {'url': 'url1', 'update_time': '1415387875'}}
{'other_key': {}, 'page': {'url': 'url3', 'update_time': '1415384938'}}
{'other_key': {}, 'page': {'url': 'url2', 'update_time': '1415381963'}}
{'other_key': {}, 'page': {'url': 'url4'}}
{'other_key': {}, 'page': {'url': 'url5'}}
```

Though, I would still follow the [`EAFP` principle](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) that Ferdinand suggested - this way you would also handle cases when `page` key is also missing. Much easier to let it fail and handle it than checking all sorts of corner cases.

Comment: how to assign json file to lines so that it must dynamically if I we 1 million lines then it will not load right so that's why

Comment: `lines = sorted(json_string, key=lambda k: k['modified'], reverse=True)
TypeError: string indices must be integers` i am getting error.

Answer (score 17):

```
# sort json
lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda k: k['page'].get('update_time', 0), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def get_sortest_key(a: dict, o: dict):
    v = None
    k = None
    for key, value in a.items():
        if v is None:
            v = value
            k = key
            continue
        if v > value:
            v = value
            k = key
    o.update({k: v})
    a.pop(k)
    if a:
        get_sortest_key(a, o)
    else:
        return


def call(o):
    a = {'a': 9, 'b': 1, 'c': 3, 'k': 3, 'l': -1, 's': 100}
    z = get_sortest_key(a, o)
    print(o)


o={}    
call(o)
```

Comment: Adding some explanation of how your code addresses the original problem would be useful.